# To publish a Microsoft Edge extension, is payment required for registration?

Tags: microsoft-edge, browser-extension, microsoft-edge-extension, browser-addons, microsoft-edge-chromium

I have build an extension to publish on Microsoft Edge Add-ons and I wanted to know if the registration is free or paid to submit extensions. Can anyone help with information on this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no registration fee involved in submitting extensions to the Microsoft Edge program.

Please refer to the link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/publish/create-dev-account) for step-by-step instructions to register as Microsoft Edge extension developer on [Partner Center](https://partner.microsoft.com/dashboard/microsoftedge/public/login?ref=dd).

Hope this information helps. Thank you!